# Pyspark: how to select a subset of a dataset and save it?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset that I ma trying to manage with `pyspark` and for which I would like to select a subset. Let me say that I am quite new to `spark`, `scala` and `pyspark` in general.

This is what I am doing.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as fs

spark  = SparkSession.builder\
                  .master("local")\
                  .enableHiveSupport()\
                  .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", '16g')
spark.conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '16')
spark.conf.set("spark.shuffle.compress", 'True')
spark.conf.set("spark.python.worker.memory", '16g')
spark.conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", '10')

sc = spark.sparkContext


%%time
f = "myData"
schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Code", StringType(), True),
    StructField("bool", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("lat", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("lon", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("v1", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("v2", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("v3", FloatType(), True)])

df = spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).load(f)
df.show()

+--------------------+----+----+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|                  ID|Code|bool|      lat|       lon|       v1|        v2|       v3|
+--------------------+----+----+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.377167| -71.06994|17.422535|1525319638|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37747|-71.069824|17.683573|1525319639|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37757| -71.06942|22.287935|1525319640|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37761| -71.06943|19.110023|1525319641|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.377243| -71.06952|18.904774|1525319642|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.378254| -71.06948|20.772903|1525319643|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37801| -71.06983|18.084948|1525319644|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.378693| -71.07033| 15.64326|1525319645|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.378723|-71.070335|21.093477|1525319646|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37868| -71.07034|21.851894|1525319647|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.378716| -71.07029|20.583202|1525319648|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37872| -71.07067|19.738768|1525319649|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.379112| -71.07097|20.480911|1525319650|36.853622|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37952|  -71.0708|20.526752|1525319651| 44.93808|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37902| -71.07056|20.534052|1525319652| 44.93808|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.380203|  -71.0709|19.921381|1525319653| 44.93808|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.37968|-71.071144| 20.12599|1525319654| 44.93808|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1|42.379696| -71.07114|18.760069|1525319655| 36.77853|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.38011| -71.07123|19.155525|1525319656| 36.77853|
|5ac52674ffff34c98...|IDFA|   1| 42.38022|  -71.0712|16.978994|1525319657| 36.77853|
+--------------------+----+----+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
only showing top 20 rows

CPU times: user 4 ms, sys: 4 ms, total: 8 ms
Wall time: 3.44 s
```

Let say that I would like to select the information of the first `ID`.

```
%%time
id0 = df.first().ID  ## First ID
tmp = df.filter( (df['ID'] == id0) )

CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 8 ms, total: 8 ms
Wall time: 514 ms

%%time
tmp.count()
CPU times: user 8 ms, sys: 4 ms, total: 12 ms
Wall time: 1min 25s
Out[5]:
3299
```

The output is a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` with `3299` rows. The first question is why is taking so long time to count `3299` rows?

The second question is: how can I save it or transform it as a normal dataframe? Is it normal that is taking so long to convert it to a normal dataframe?

```
%%time
result_pdf = tmp.select("*").toPandas()
CPU times: user 60 ms, sys: 12 ms, total: 72 ms
Wall time: 3min 33s
```

Comment: you have done the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008180/pyspark-count-on-pyspark-sql-dataframe-dataframe-takes-long-time). So it will be better to continue under the same thread the discussion about performance

Comment: @ggeop it is in somehow similar but I did not get an answer before and I did not understand how to solve the issue.

Comment: I answer you in your previous question about the performance. It not an issue, this is how Spark works. Don't compare it with Pandas!!

Comment: @ggeop I do not want to compare it with Pandas. My questions: is it normal that it works like that?

Comment: YESSS Its normal :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, both your questions are related to the RAM.

1. The fact that Spark doesn't load data in RAM (contrary to Pandas) explain the slowness. The thing is 3200 row is **not big enough** to use a Spark I would say.

   If you can use Pandas, better using it because it will be faster.

   If you want to scale to multiple millions / billions and you can't load your data in RAM (because Pandas is really greedy : for 1GB dataset, you will probably need 10GB of RAM) so you can Out Of Memory your computer fast.

   So, if you got multiple GB or TB (or even PB), **Spark** is  for you. If you got less than that and can fit your data in RAM, then use **Pandas**

So the speed scaling is not enough fast for you to see the difference but Spark will probably be as fast for 3K data and 3M, because it splits execution, distribute the calculation, then gather it again etc. Contrary to Pandas that does all the calculation in RAM.

2. The conversion speed (`toPandas()`) is also slow, because you're **loading** all the data into memory (RAM) so the transfer. It's really like loading your data with Pandas and then filtering.

If you want to save it, the best way is :

```
data.write.parquet("data.parquet")
```

or

```
data.write.csv("data.csv")
```

Further documentation : 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html

Comment: thanks but I dot not understand the answer. How can I allocate more RAM? Why do you say 3200?

Comment: To allocate 2g, you can do that : 
```from pyspark import SparkContext
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '2g')
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")```

Comment: But the thing is Spark doesn't need a lot of RAM to work because every result is stored elsewhere and accessed later. Contrary to Pandas that load and calculate everything in RAM

Comment: Now, you got your answer, so if you need, you can read further about "Map-Reduce" and how it works or ask another question. But please mark this one as solved and validate it. Thanks

Comment: but I have already allocated `16g` of memory in my workflow.  `spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", '16g')`

Comment: And ? Can you just make sentences and question if you want help